# How can i export a table in ms word with 30,000 rows and 63 columns using java?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, streaming

I was using ApachePOI, but it doesn't hyave the streaming mechanism for ms word, so I am getting outOfMemeory Exception (I am working with 4GB of RAM)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem once with a similar situation, what I did was I increased my page file and it worked again, the problem is that you will eventually reach the limit again as the db grows. In windows you can try increasing you page file.

Try it : http://www.thewindowsclub.com/increase-page-file-size-virtual-memory-windows